# Determine all eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors of the given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I am studying for a test and I ran into a book problem I cannot seem to do.

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        6 & 3 & -3 \\
        -5 & -2 & 2 \\
        0 & 0 & -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

is the matrix in the problem. Below is my work. Any help is appreciated.
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        6-λ & 3 & -3 \\
        -5 & -2-λ & 2 \\
        0 & 0 & -1-λ \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

expanding upon the bottom row I get:
$$(-1-λ) * \begin{vmatrix}
        6-λ & 3\\
        -5 & -2-λ\\
        \end{vmatrix} = 0$$
$$(-1-λ)(λ^2-4λ-12)=0$$
$$(-1-λ)(λ+2)(λ-6)=0$$
This my eigenvalues are: $λ = -1, -2, 6$

Now when I attempt to find the eigenvectors is where I run into problems. My professor told us we should always have a row of complete $0$'s or else we did something wrong. I get one when I use $λ = -1$ and end up with $v$ = $\begin{bmatrix}
        x\\
        y\\
        z\\
        \end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{1}{4}z\\
        \frac{3}{4}z\\
        z\\
        \end{bmatrix}$ which seems plausible. When I attempt to apply the eigenvalue $λ = -2$ is where I am running in to trouble. When I row reduce I do not end up with a row of complete $0$'s. I instead end up with $$\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & \frac{3}{8} & \frac{-1}{2} \\
        0 & 1 & \frac{1}{30} \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
        =
       \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        0\\
        0\\
        \end{bmatrix}$$
Again, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I get eigenvalues $3,1,-1$ in Matlab. Perhaps you have an arithmetic error?

Comment: @Ian That is very possible. I'll have to redo the eigenvalue part and see what I get.

Comment: Indeed you do: in calculating the determinant of the 2x2 minor, you did not include the off-diagonal terms. So you should have $\lambda^2-4\lambda+3$ instead. That fixes your eigenvalues.

Comment: your eigenvalues are wrong, it should be $-1,1,3$

Comment: I see! I'll give the problem another try and see where I get calculating the e-vectors with those values. Thanks!